# Print data value of array

Tags: javascript

I have a array that has IDs in JavaScript:

```
["1649545","1649546","1649547"] etc.
```

And I want to print the values of this array in a URL, so something like this the foreach function of PHP does;

```
foreach
       www.google.com/[valueofarray]
end
```

I know the solution could be very easy, but I just cannot manage to find it.

Comment: If you can't find it, you might have to code it yourself!

Comment: So you can't google `javascript foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle and used a for loop this is without the use of jQuery but only javascript. I made an example array called myArray, I used `.length` so that javascript stops when he's been through all of the strings in the example array.

```
var myArray = ['12345', '123456', '1234567'];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log('http://foo.com/' + myArray[i]);
    // alert(myArray[i]);
}
```

See it work (and be sure to open your browsers console or use alert instead for viewing the output)

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6Lbbz0b/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var p='http:',a=["1649545","1649546","1649547"],u='www.google.com';for(i=0; i<a.length; ++i) console.log([p,'',u,a[i]].join('/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var idArray = ["1649545","1649546","1649547"];
var url = "www.google.com/";

idArray.forEach(function(id){
    console.log("http://" + url + id); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tcmn2Lda/